# SQL null date comparison

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, null

I have two queries offered on employee database (that we check whether they are equivalent or not), and I need to show whether we need to use IS NULL value for determining if our table would give correct result or not. We have three attributes of the **salary** table, which are **to_date** and **from_date** and **emp_no**, where by agreement **to_date** will have NULL if **salary** row is still valid (i.e. salary is still up to date for **emp_no**, therefore **to_date** is NULL).
These are queries being compared:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM salaries
WHERE from_date <= '1996-12-31' AND to_date >= '1996-12-01';
```

and

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   salaries
WHERE  from_date <= '1996-12-31' AND (to_date >= '1996-12-01' OR to_date IS NULL) ;
```

Goal is to find number of employees who received salary in December and only condition to receive a salary is to be employeed have salary for at least one day in December.

Comment: You would then remove all the rows of people who started receiving one salary before from_date and those that stopped receiving salary after to_date.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for employees who worked at least one day in December 1996.

This looks like a good spot to use date function `overlaps()`:

```
where (from_date, coalesce(to_date, now())) 
    overlaps ('1996-12-01'::date, interval '1' month)
```

Actually the above expression has an edge cas when an employee's last day of work is December 1st (in which case I think you want to count it in, while this doesn't). So instead we could just write:

```
where
    from_date < '1997-01-01'::date
    and (to_date is null or to_date >= '1996-12-01'::date)
```

Comment: That's fine, but I am asking for the argument which one out of those two queries is better for finding all the result, or which one is wrong.